# What is meaning of this cron expression 0 50 13 1 1/1 ? *?

Tags: cronexpression

What does the following Cron expression mean?

```
0 50 13 1 1/1 ? *
```

- `0`: means 0 seconds
- `50`: means 50 minutes
- `13`: means every 13 hours

But I don't know the meaning of `1 1/1 ? *`.

Does the `1` mean "every day of the month"? Does the `1/1` mean each month of the year?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about a non-standard dialect of cron expressions (it has a seconds field, one field contains a `?`, and `1/1` is not POSIX), but fails to mention which dialect is used here. Unless the question is edited to include the precise version of `cron`/`crontab`, it can't be answered.

Answer (score 2):

See the [`crontab(5)`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man5/crontab.5) manual:

A line in a user crontab file has the form

```
minute hour day-of-month month day-of-week command
```

Your line:

```
0 50 13 1 1/1 ? *
```

Your interpretation does not make sense, as there is no "seconds" field.  The "hour" field is "50".  This literally means "At time 50:00 on the 13th of January, if it's a Monday, run the command '? *'".

If this is using [CronTrigger](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm) from Oracle, or [Quartz Enterprise Job Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html) (which seems to be the same thing), the line means "At 13:50:00, on the 1st of every month, any day of the week, every year".

The `1 1/1` means "the 1st of every month (starting at January)". Had it been `1 1/2` it would have meant "the 1st of every second month (starting at January)".

The final `? *` means "any day of the week, every year".

Comment: It's a nonstandard format, given the `?` and the seconds field; see for instance [Oracle's CronTrigger](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm). Also, the `1/1` would be equivalent to `1` in some dialects, while while it would mean `*` in others.

Comment: @Rhymoid Updated the answer.

Comment: See my explanation for the close vote in the OP. This question is meaningless without an explicit mention of the dialect. Any answer would be a guess.

Comment: Hi I am using Quartz API .In this API the expression looks like 13:50:00

Comment: @user5747838 Please update the text of the question with all relevant information.

Comment: @Kusalananda Now I got the idea .You explain well

Comment: @user5747838 Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).